# jQuery Selecting elements by dynamic name with square brackets (fiddle incl)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this fiddle work:
http://jsfiddle.net/gAHwW/

```
function $escape(string) { 
    return string.replace(/\\(\[|\]\\)/g,'\\\\$1');
}

$(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        alert($escape( $(this).attr('id') )); // to show you what the escape does

        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).hide(); // doesn't work
        $('#' + $escape( $(this).attr('id') )).hide(); // doesn't work
        $('#alsosquare[]').hide(); // doesn't work

        //$(this).hide(); // works
        //$('#alsosquare\\[\\]').hide(); // works
    });
});​
```

I need to select elements by their name/id dynamically, and their names/ids can have square brackets.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the names & ids can have square brackets, do you mean they are arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to double escape(`\\`) the brackets.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k3YyX/

---

Here's a quote from [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (such as **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~**) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: **\\**. For example, if you have an element with **id="foo.bar"**, you can use the selector **$("#foo\\.bar")**.

---

**Update:**

Here's your fiddle, in working condition: http://jsfiddle.net/gAHwW/1/

All I did was replace `'\\\\$1'` with this `'\\$1'` in your `$escape` function.

Comment: How about trying to make my fiddle work? When I store the resulting string after the replace (to add the `\\`) it doesn't work.